# sIFR: How to prevent "click to enable text selection" in Firefox?

Tags: sifr

In Firefox, after you clicking on other places of the page and scrolling the page, you have to click on the flash text once to enable the text selection. Another similar issue occurs in Safari. But in Safari, the flash text cannot even be selected.

How to prevent these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no `wmode` specified for the sIFR replacements, that should help.

Comment: Thank you. But what if the sIFR replacements have background image?

Comment: Try removing the floats applied to the ancestor elements. And yea, you can't do that either, so perhaps best not to use sIFR. It's a browser/Flash issue, really.

Also, some browsers on Linux do not support Flash transparency, so they'll still be unable to see the background image.